# Create JSON File with Format C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to create JSON file in the following format:

```
"Result": [
         [ "Date", "Name", "Address", "Age" ],
         [ "MMDDYYYY", "Name1", "Add1", "15" ],
         [ "MMDDYYYY", "Name2", "Add2", "20" ]
```

The Result's data is a `List<JArray>` which is filled by `List<string>` which is filled from a `DataTable` as following:

```
var jArrayList = new List<JArray>();
var rowData = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var rowData = new List<string>(table.Columns.Count);
   DataRow dataRow = table.Rows[i];

   foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
   {
      if (i > 0)
      {
         rowData.Add(dataRow[dataColumn].ToString());
      }
    }

    if (rowData.Any())
    {
       jArrayList.Add(new JArray(rowData));
    }
 }

 if (jArrayList.Any())
 {
    var jobj = new JObject( new JProperty("Result",
                            from p in jArrayList
                            select p));
     jObjList.Add(jobj);
  }

  var outputJson = new JObject(new JProperty("Entries",
                                        from p in jObjList
                                        select p));
  var outputString = outputJson.ToString();
```

When i execute this code it is writing everything in new line:

```
"Result": [
    [
      "Date",
      "Name",
      "Address",
      "Age"
    ],
    [
      "MMDDYYYY",
      "Name1",
      "Add1",
      "15"
    ],
    [
      "MMDDYYYY",
      "Name2",
      "Add2",
      "20"
    ],
```

How to format it to be written in this way?

```
"Result": [
     [ "Date", "Name", "Address", "Age" ],
     [ "MMDDYYYY", "Name1", "Add1", "15" ],
     [ "MMDDYYYY", "Name2", "Add2", "20" ]
```

Comment: Sorry for probably ignorant question, but why you need to create it in this exact format ?

Comment: @mybirthname because it will have a very large data. So with new lines it will be more size and not readable.

Comment: You should not be displaying a low level format to users anyway - JSON is not meant to be seen by users - that's what UIs are for!

Comment: @toadflakz it will not be used for end-user, it is for another level of development which sometimes needs observation. I am just asking if it is possible or it is impossible?

Comment: it is possible, but you will need to parse it through an algorithm or a regex

Comment: @meJustAndrew How? could you please write it or even a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
string json = "\"Result\": [\r\n    [\r\n      \"Date\",\r\n      \"Name\",\r\n      \"Address\",\r\n      \"Age\"\r\n    ],\r\n    [\r\n      \"MMDDYYYY\",\r\n      \"Name1\",\r\n      \"Add1\",\r\n      \"15\"\r\n    ],\r\n    [\r\n      \"MMDDYYYY\",\r\n      \"Name2\",\r\n      \"Add2\",\r\n      \"20\"\r\n    ],";
            var withoutEnter = json.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
            var splited = withoutEnter.Split('[');
            var formattedJson = splited[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < splited.Length; i++)
            {
                formattedJson = formattedJson + "[" + splited[i] + "\n";
            }
```

I have copy-pasted your json sample and parsed it to remove all enters, then added back enter for each group. Sorry for the messy code :)

Comment: Your solution is removing **`[`** which must be there

Comment: well, you definitely gave me the idea .. But instead of use `Split()` I will use `Replace()`
 As well `Json.ToString(Formatting.None)` and no need `for` loop
Thank you